# Basic SQL: How to use properties of one table as a lookup on other tables

Tags: sql

Suppose I have three Tables:

```
Table A:

Column A | Column B
   Z          Q
   Q          Z


Table Z:

Column A | Column B
   100        50


Table Q:

Column A | Column B
   200        75
```

What I'm looking to do is produce a result like the following using Table A as a sort of guide:

```
 DESIRED RESULT:

@Temp Table
  Column A | Column B
     100        75
     200        50
```

I was hoping to be able to perform something too this effect in SQL as a Stored Procedure but I'm having trouble getting the results I want.  Could use some help.

Comment: Yeah I figured so, I just can't figure out how exactly to use the property value from Table A to determine which table (z or Q) to join on, I guess it would be both... but forgive me I'm a javascript guy mainly so my server skills are pretty basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirements, here is one way to do it, but it won't work if you have multiple values in your z and q tables unless you have something to join on:

```
select 
  case when a.cola = 'Z' then z.cola else q.cola end cola,
  case when a.colb = 'Z' then z.colb else q.colb end colb
from tablea a, tableq q, tablez z
```

[Sample Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5999c/2)

Comment: @CollinEstes -- glad I could, best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing in the contrived example to use the same column name on different tables, but I believe what you're trying to describe is a classic many-to-many relationship.

If so, your `Table A` would be your cross-reference table.

Unfortunately for this to work you need to have related foreign key values stored in your cross-reference table, not the actual values as you propose.

This is probably what you're after:

```
Table A
QA |ZA
1  |2
3  |4


Table Q
QA |QB
1  |100
3  |200


Table Z
ZA |ZB
2  |300
4  |400


SELECT Q.QB, Z.ZB
FROM Q INNER JOIN A ON Q.QA = A.QA
  INNER JOIN Z ON Z.ZA = A.ZA
```

...results in:

```
QB |ZB
100|300
200|400
```